# What is the proper module/directive/filter/etc syntax in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I've seen modules, and the directives, filters, etc defined in those modules, written different ways and I was just curious if there was a benefit to one over the other.

For example, I have a module that I am defining a directive in that looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>'
    }
});
```

But I also see it written like the following a lot, with the directive definition essentially inside the the module:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>'
    }
});
```

Which way is better? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same.

`module(name,dependencies)` returns the module previously defined.The difference between the 2 is in the first exemple you put the module into a variable.Which in exemple 1 is unnecessary.

> But I also see it written like the following a lot,  with the
>   directive definition essentially inside the the module:

it's not inside the module,you are calling a method of the module,directive,factory... are methods of the module.

it's called method chaining.